# edge modes of topological insulators?

Tags: topological-insulators

in a paper  http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.2273 there is a possibility shown that gapped modes at edges can exist for non-trivial interacting topological systems and mathematically shown that gapless modes get replaced by zero's of green's function, I don't understand what does zero of Green's function represent ? and Is it really  possible to have gapped modes for interacting non-trivial topological systems because for non-trivial topological systems there are always gapless edges modes present

Comment: Zero of Green's function mean that there is no quasiparticle anymore. It is no longer a good picture to think about weakly interacting fermions. In this example, when the edge modes become gapped (without breaking symmetry), it means the system is NOT topological.

Comment: @MengCheng so does it mean that we can have topological phase transition between two different topological systems without closing band gap?

Comment: If the gap does not close, then it is not a phase transition. The point is that these are the same topological phase even though they are classified as being different when the system is not interacting.